# How to populate winform chart with a math function?

Tags: c#, winforms, math, charts

I am using a Windows Forms App. I have a transfer function H(s) from which I need to generate a spline and a step line chart. I have trouble understanding how I am suppose to pass the function to the charts in order to generate them.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chart1.Titles.Add("Chart Impuls");
            chart2.Titles.Add("Chart Treapta");

            chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY("2", "5");
            chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY("3", "-7");
            chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY("5", "9");

            chart2.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY("2", "5");
            chart2.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY("3", "-7");
            chart2.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY("5", "9");
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double K = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1_constanta.Text);
            double d = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2_coeficient.Text);
            double w = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3_pulsatia.Text);

            //functia de transfer H(s)
            for (int s = 0; s < 10; s++)
            {
                double H = (K * Math.Pow(w, 2)) / (Math.Pow(s, 2) + 2 * d * w + Math.Pow(w, 2));
            }
        }
    }
```

I added some points myself for testing purposes, but how should I go about when I have a function like this?

Comment: You could use the `s` for the _X_ and `H` for the _Y_. `chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(s, H);` Don't forget the clear the points, when refreshing the chart.

Comment: That worked. And thanks for the clear points part too.